# How to restrict Response:download base on route filter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

### Details

- I am using Laravel 4.0
- I am not sure why all my user logos couldn't load
- I am 100% sure that I have those logos in the right path, in the right place.
- They display fine throughout my application, except that URL `/api/url/decode`
- I want to allow `/files/logo_path/{id}` url, if they provided me the right api_key that I set.
- Again, please note that the URL =  `/files/logo_path/{id}` is not meant to be accessible by everyone.
- Can someone tell what did I do wrong here ?

### This is what I've tried

### routes.php

```
// API
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function(){
    Route::get('url', array('before' => 'api', 'uses' => 'UrlController@index'));
    Route::get('url/decode', 'UrlController@decode');

    Route::get('files/logo_path/{id}', function($id)
        {
            $logo_path = app_path() . '/files/logo_path/' . User::find($id)->logo_path;
            return Response::download($logo_path);
        });
});
```

### filters.php

```
// API
Route::filter('api', function() {

    if (Input::get('key') != '*********')
    {
        return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404);
    }
});
```

### Result

[image]

### Updated

`<img id="Company Logo" src="/files/logo_path/{{{ $distributor['user']['id'] or '' }}}" alt="logo" height="60px" width="200px">`

Comment: Can you add the code of how you link to the image?

Comment: Sure will do. Give me 1 mn.

Comment: What do you get if you go to /files/logo_path/{an id that exists} ? Do you get an image there?

Have you tried using Intervention and returning an image response?

Comment: If I go to it, it won't display, but it will download an image for that id.

Comment: Keep in that I've been using this. through out my application and it's work.

Comment: In order to display it, I will have to throw that link in an image, then it will.

Comment: Not sure why it would have worked elsewhere and not here, but I'm still going to recommend this package: http://image.intervention.io/api/response -- I've never had an issue displaying images in a protected folder using this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with filters. The issue is how you are trying to display the data.

A `Response::download()` is to ask the browser to prompt the user to save or open the file.

But you are putting that linked code within `img<>` html - which is used to display the image inline on the page.

They are not able to be mixed together.

If you want to allow users to only download an image they are allowed to access - you would leave your current route unchanged - but change your view code to

```
<a href="{{{ /files/logo_path/{{{ $distributor['user']['id'] or '' }}}""> Click here to download your file</a>
```

If you want to allow users to view the image on page (only if they have access) - then you would leave your view code unchanged as:

```
<img id="Company Logo" src="/files/logo_path/{{{ $distributor['user']['id'] or '' }}}" alt="logo" height="60px" width="200px">
```

But change your route code to this:

```
Route::get('files/logo_path/{id}', function($id)
        {
            $logo_path = app_path() . '/files/logo_path/' . User::find($id)->logo_path;
            return file_get_contents($logo_path);
        });
```